# Robot command translation: Calculating circle radius from forward velocity and yaw rate.

Tags: geometry

MORE INFO :)
I'm writing a driver for a robot control program.
The robot only understands a command with arguments of (Forward velocity, Radius).

ex: (200mm/s, 200mm) will cause the robot to move in a circle of radius 200mm at a tangential velocity of 200mm/s

The control software written sends me commands containing (Forward velocity, Yaw rate) arguments.

How can I calculate the radius of the circle, a robot would make, with a certain yaw rate and forward velocity?

Comment: I think you may need to define "yaw rate" for us.

Comment: I'd like to have it defined too. That's all the documentation says. That I will be provided tangential speed and yaw rate, and that needs to be translated to tangential speed and circle radius... I THINK it means the angular velocity of the robot. Still confusing to think about.

Answer (score 0):

If the yaw rate is $r$ degrees per second
(I will use degrees here - radians would work just as well),
it will take $360/r$ seconds to turn a full circle.

If the velocity is $v$ meters per second,
in $360/r$ seconds it will travel
$v*360/r$ meters.
Since this will be a full circle
with circumference
$v*360/r$ meters,
the radius will be the circumference divided by
$2 \pi$
or $v*360/(r*2 \pi) = 180v/(\pi r)$ meters

Answer (score 0):

Assuming yaw rate is the angular velocity $\omega$ measured in radians per second and linear speed $V$,the radius
$$ R = \frac{V}{\omega}.$$